# Skip certain combination of os and version in travis-ci

Tags: r, travis-ci

On Travis-ci, I would like to skip some of the combinations of os and versions.

Specifically, suppose I have an R project.  My current ".travis.yml" looks like

```
language: r

r:
  - oldrel
  - release
  - devel  

os:
  - linux
  - osx
```

But I would like to skip `devel` with `osx` (since `devel` is not quite ready for this platform yet). Can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`matrix`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Build-Matrix) argument to configure combinations you want to include or exclude. In your case:

```
matrix:
  exclude:
  - os: osx
    r: devel
```